# Is there any way to tell which of my messages have been auto-forwarded?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I'm using Gmail, but I suppose this would be useful in any webmail application.

Someone I know got into my Gmail account and set up an auto-forwarding address (`Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> Forwarding`). Forwarding is turned off now, and I've secured the account, but I'd like to know what they got. Nothing shows up in the `Sent Mail` folder.

Comment: I would find this very helpful, but I'm dubious.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what the other drop-down in Gmail's Forwarding Settings was selected:

[Gmail Forwarding Settings http://geekcubed.org/random/gmail_fwding.png](http://geekcubed.org/random/gmail_fwding.png)

The options are fairly self-explanatory. If it was configured to `Delete Google Mails's copy` then there is not going to be any record of what was forwarded.  If one of the other settings were selected, then the mail would still be in the appropriate folder (Inbox or Archive).

Even if the delete option wasn't selected, you have to suspect that the culprit may have accessed your account again and just manually deleted mail.

Hopefully this will be a lesson - **never give out your username and password** even to people you know.

**Edit**
You are going to have to assume that [they] got hold of everything. Every account that points to that email address (e-commerce sites, banking, any sort of membership) should be assumed to be compromised, and will need to be checked and secured. They could quite easily have recovered the password to those accounts via your email and then deleted all trace

Comment: Even if the email is still in the inbox, I interpreted the question as "I know forwarding was turned on, but I don't know when.  Is there any way to see which emails in my inbox were forwarded?"  On a per message basis, I don't think there is an indicator that the message was forwarded by a filter (global or an actual filter setup by the user).

Comment: @rchern: exactly. I'm not worried about *not getting* my messages, I'm worried about which messages the *other person* got.

Comment: I would assume that seeing your inbox, you would recognised which messages you had, or hadn't seen before (even if they are all marked as read).

Comment: The problem is that this occurred some time ago, AFAIK. Since the forwarding was set to leave the mail marked "Unread", I have no way of knowing if it's been seen by somebody else or not. If the messages had been marked "read", I would have noticed much sooner.